# Is orthogonal diagonalization of real symmetric matrix unique for each eigenvalues' permutation?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

$C$: real symmetric matrix ($C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n})$ 
$C=PDP^{-1}$ (orthogonal diagonalization of $C$)
$P$: orthogonal matrix whose column vectors are eigenvectors of $C$ 
$D$: diagonal matrix whose main diagonals are eigenvalues of $C$

Is orthogonal diagonalization $C=PDP^{-1}$ is unique for each $D$(each eigenvalues' permutation)?

(Add)

Counterexample:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
 a & 0 \\
 0 & b
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 a & 0 \\
 0 & b
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$

$
\begin{pmatrix}
 a & 0 \\
 0 & b
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 a & 0 \\
 0 & b
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$

Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of
$
\begin{pmatrix}
 a & 0 \\
 0 & b
\end{pmatrix}
$
are 
$
\lambda_1=a, x_1=(t, 0) \\ 
\lambda_2=b, x_2=(0, k) \\
t, k \in \mathbb{R}
$

So orthogonal diagonalization for each eigenvalues' permutaion is not unique.

Comment: Yes, it is. While many diagonalizing non-orthogonal matrix $P$ exist, there is only one that satisfies $P^TP=I$. One way to say this is that with a subspace spanned by a vector $v$ there is only one vector within that subspace that as unit norm.

Comment: @KBS Could you show more detailed proof?

Comment: What details do you want? The columns of $P$ are orthogonal because the matrix $C$ is real symmetric. Then, you can just normalize the columns to get an orthogonal matrix. In fact, there are two vectors with unit norm in each one dimensional subspace. If $v$ has norm one, then $-v$ also has norm one.

Comment: @KBS I can't deduce uniqueness from "there are two vectors with unit norm in each one dimensional subspace. If $v$ has norm one, then $−v$ also has norm one".

Comment: There is uniqueness modulo sign permutations for the matrix $P$.

Comment: @KBS Added counterexample

Comment: The eigenvectors need to be normalized.

Comment: @KBS Eigenvectors in counterexample are already normalized: (1,0), (0,1), (0, -1)

Comment: What are $x_1$ and $x_2$. Your addition lacks details. Also, I already mentioned in a previous message that "There is uniqueness modulo sign permutations for the matrix $P$".

Comment: @KBS The identity matrix is a symmetric (diagonal) matrix but for this one, any orthogonal matrix $P$ satisfies $P^TIP=I,$ no? So it seems that for at least the identity matrix (which is symmetric), the orthogonal diagonalization isn't unique.